# How to add robotframework-pabot process?

Tags: robotframework

Im new with using pabot and I am wondering how to have more test cases to run parallel. I can only execute 4 cases in parallel.

Does it have anything to do with the machine's specification

I Have tried adding processes in the --processes but when it reached beyond 4, no processes were added after that.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly you have 4-core processor. If I understand official readme.md correctly, number of cores is the maximum number of threads possible to run in pallarel.

> --processes [NUMBER OF PROCESSES]
> How many parallel executors to use (default max of 2 and cpu count)

Comment: We used a machine with 24-core processor, and run pabot with "--processes 6" in the command. Only 4 browsers were running.